# Eclipse Compiling C Code With G++ not GCC

Tags: eclipse, gcc

I have search around and cannot find the answer to my question. I have installed MinGW GCC compiler only (No G++). I have sent the path and can compile "hello world" from the command line. Next, in eclipse, I have created a new "C" project with a "C" source file. I have also set my include folder.

I have the same "Hello World" code, but when I go to compile, I get "G++ not in path". This is expected as because I don't have G++ installed. However, I do not seem to be able to tell eclipse that I want to use the installed GCC compiler.

If I go to Properties->C/C++ Build->Settings->GCC C Compiler the command reads "gcc". So I don't understand what I doing wrong.

Any pointer will be very gratefully received.

Kind Regards,
Harold Clements

Comment: Try to compile on the terminal (maybe thru a builder like `make`). Then get an editor (or configure your Eclipse to make it use the same compilation command that you are typing). Don't forget to pass `-Wall -Wextra -g` to `gcc` (or to `g++` or `clang`)

Comment: I am completely confused. My question is really how to I configure Eclipse to the use the GCC compiler and not the g++.

Comment: @haroldjclements Sorry, haven't used it in a while. Just wondering, do you have much invested in using Eclipse? you might try SublimeText3 (you might need to also download some add-on packages) or Qt Creator (which includes make tools). They run faster.

Comment: To be honourest, no I don't. I have been using Notepad++ and just wanted something a little more useful when it comes to code completion and debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check which type of the project you created in Eclipse and toolchain selected for the project.

Comment: Thank you for your response.I have selected a C project, created a C source file and selected MinGW GCC. If I go to Properties->C/C++ Build->Settings->GCC C Compiler the command reads "gcc".Is there anything that I have missed?

Comment: Properties->C/C++ Builder->Tool Chain Editor->"Select Tools..." try removing all C++ related things and play with different builder. I don't have MinGW installed, but selected this toolchain - it builds using some fallback to GCC.

Comment: There is also a chance that your source file has ".C" (capital C extension) that may be treated as C++ file - see this Properties->C/C++ general->Filetypes

Comment: Thank you all. After removing all the C++ build related items and throwing in a reboot, all is good in the world.

Happy Holidays....Harold Clements